# Given a timestamp column, how can I make intervals of two hours and display in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp column like :

```
2018-03-24 11:23:48,
2017-06-23 16:53:16,
2017-06-23 15:24:37
```

The range is from 7 am till 5 pm and I want to make a column which tells in which slot(2-hour slots starting from 7 am) does the timestamp fall into.

I tried various functions liked Pandas. Grouper but resulted in errors.

```
department_wise.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='2H')).count()
```

but it said

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

The actual results I want is like:

```
2018-03-24 11:23:48 this should fall into 9:01-11:00 slot
2017-06-23 15:24:37 this should fall into 15:01-17:00 slot. etc.
```

If anybody has some other approach. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = ['2018-03-24 11:23:48',
      '2017-06-23 16:53:16',
      '2017-06-23 15:24:37']

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dt}, dtype='datetime64[ns]')

bins=[x for x in range(7, 18, 2)]
labels=['(7-9]', '(9-11]', '(11-13]', '(13-15]', '(15-17]']

df['window'] = pd.cut(x=df.date.dt.hour, bins=bins, include_lowest=True, labels=labels)
```

[image]

- Incidentally, `(7-9]` = 07:00-08:59. `(` or `)` mean inclusive and `[` or `]` are exclusive.